# Can Firebase ML Kit be used to detect how likely a photo contains an object present into another photo?

Tags: firebase, firebase-mlkit

I would like to implement a webcrawler that would be able to, given a photo of an object, search for it in a specific website.

I'm looking into [Firebase ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit) to do the job, more specificaly the [Objects detection section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/object-detection) but it is still unclear to me if that would be the right tool.

Anyone knows how could I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing photos (or searching for photos) is not a use-case that ML Kit offers a pre-built model for.

The closest I can think of is running the [ML Kit label extraction model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/label-images) on both images, and then checking if both return the same label(s). But even then you need to have all photo's locally already.

If you want something closer, you'll have to build a model yourself. But even then, you're likely going to need to build an extensive web service that searches web sites and pre-labels a lot of images.